# How to access Vue.prototype in external js file?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

```
"vue": "^2.4.4"
```

I defined properties in main.js:

```
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
  baseURL: {
    value: process.env.API_ROOT,
    writable: false
  }
});
```

I have another js file named version.js in src/common

```
import Vue from "vue";
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
console.log("---------------------version start---------------------")
console.log("prototype 1:", Vue.prototype)
console.log("baseURL 1:", Vue.prototype.baseURL)
console.log("---------------------version end---------------------")

console.log("---------------------app start---------------------")
console.log("prototype 2:", app)
console.log("baseURL 2:", app.baseURL)
console.log("---------------------app end---------------------")
```

I can not understand the console log:
prototype 1 contains the baseURL but baseURL 1 is undefined.
prototype 2 didn't contains baseURL and baseURL 2 is undefined.

If I want to get the baseURL in version.js. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that only `.env` properties prefixed with `VUE_APP_` make it into your bundled files.

> [Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)
>
> Note that only `NODE_ENV`, `BASE_URL`, and variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`.

Change your `.env` file to

```
VUE_APP_API_ROOT=https://whatever/
```

Second, this is exactly what [Vue plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) are for...

> 4. Add some Vue instance methods by attaching them to Vue.prototype.

You can [author your own plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) very simply like this

```js
// base-url-plugin.js
export default {
  install: Vue => {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "baseURL", {
      value: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT ?? "https://some-default/",
      writable: false
    })
  }
}
```

```js
import Vue from "vue"
import baseUrlPlugin from "./path/to/base-url-plugin.js"

// install the plugin first
Vue.use(baseUrlPlugin)

// now create your root Vue instance
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

You just need to ensure your plugin is installed before creating the root `Vue` instance.

Comment: how to make sure my plugin is installed before creating the root Vue instance?

Comment: It's your code man, just make sure you run that `Vue.use({...})` bit before `let app = new Vue({...})`. I've updated my answer to try and make it clearer

Comment: Is there any common place I can init ,just like java spring beans. and then I can use it all over the project.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The code above is only in one place